# need to call session_start() before <!DOCTYPE HTML .....etc

Tags: session, doctype

In order to fix an IE9 bug I had to put the 'DOCTYPE' declaration at the top of the page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <?php
     require_once 'navBar.php';
 ?>
```

By putting the DOCTYPE at the top of the file, I fixed an IE9 'bug.'

The 'bug' in IE9 was -- without the DOCTYPE at the file's top -- any div that had inline-block style would ignore the inline-block style and would be stacked vertically.

I have 3 divs on the page with inline-block style and in Firefox and the Android browser the 3 divs with inline-block appear on one row, horizontally left-to-right.

But in IE9, I had to add the DOCTYPE as the 1st line (not the 2nd line, not after the php section at the top -- DOCTYPE had to be the 1st line).

THEN and only then will IE9 honor the inline-block style.

THE PROBLEM IS -- inside navbar.php I call session_start().

As you know, session_start() ALSO has to be the 1st line before any browser output is sent.
You otherwise get an errmsg. like this:

```
  Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send 
  session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at 
  /homepages/42/d329883313/htdocs/ourSite/landing_page.php:2) in 
  /homepages/42/d329883313/htdocs/ourSite/navBar.php on line 1
```

(p.s. my IDE saves files as UTF-8 so the BOM is NOT the issue.  And I've already checked -- I don't have extra whitespace anywhere between the end of the DOCTYPE and the start of the session_start() either.  The session_start() is breaking because of the DOCTYPE sending something to the browser.)

MY QUESTION:

How can I keep my inline-block AND the DOCTYPE and session_start()?

It's bad that the functioning of a simple UI style is pitting two 'MUST-BE-ON-LINE-1'
code elements against each other (DOCTYPE and session_start).

Comment: Have you tried putting <?php session_start(); ?> at the top of the page with no extra spaces? PHP is server side and HTML is client side, so the PHP should be gone before IE9 interprets the page.

Comment: If the <?php occurs before the DOCTYPE then IE9 will ignore the inline-block in the divs I have on the page.  DOCTYPE **must** be on the top line of the file.  I understand your reasoning.  But when I put DOCTYPE below the closing ?> with no white space at all then IE9 will ignore my inline-block style.  Not sure why.  Maybe the web server puts something at the top of the page after processing the PHP, I don't know.

Comment: fair enough, but when you say you tried putting it straight after, do you mean after the require_once or after session_start (on its own)?

Comment: Either require_once or session_start have one thing in common: they come before the closing ?>  of the PHP block.  I'm saying that it doesn't matter WHAT is in the PHP block -- if the DOCTYPE comes after the ?> close of the PHP block, then the inline-block for the divs is ignored in IE9.  I'm finding that DOCTYPE has to be BEFORE the opening <?php on the very first line or inline-block for divs is ignored in IE9.

Comment: Yeh, I totally get what you're saying. I'm just wondering if there is something in the navbar.php file thats causing the issue. Thats why I was asking if you had tried session_start by itself, rather than including the navbar file :)

Comment: Notice the require_once 'navBar.php';  above.  There are a lot of source files in our site.  Every one of them uses that syntax, including this --> ***include 'foo.php';***   I have not been programming PHP very long and I don't remember how I started using that syntax but I've changed it all to require_once('navBar.php');  And I'm able to put DOCTYPE at the top -- the code sample above in my question now works fine with no error about the session or headers.  There are three 'require_once' inside navbar.php and switching to ***require_once('filename.php');*** seems to have fixed it.

Comment: glad you managed to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to switch from require_once 'somefile.php';

to

require_once('somefile.php');

Although Firefox and the Android browser were fine with the first style, IE9 had a quirk: it would ignore the inline-block style for divs.